# urllib to mirror and store http status simultaneously

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, urllib, mirror

I adore the urllib module and I use it for massive, constant retrieval of data with Python 2.7. Like so...

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.example.com/mirror_me.txt","mirror_me.txt")
```

The service I am mirroring has very hard and fast rules about how often I can hit their service. It's almost always a 200 response when I hit but occasionally I need to watch out for 404 because they have a, sometimes, faulty process on their end.

I do know I can check the response code this way...

```
a=urllib.urlopen('http://www.example.com/mirror_me.txt')
a.getcode()
200
```

Problem is I don't know how to combine the two, so now I'm having to send two requests which is inefficient and doubles my hits against their server.
Ideally I'd like the following.....

```
if 200:
   mirror
elif 404:
   notify me....
```

Maybe my answer does not lie in urllib, but I appreciate any pointers anyone has.
JW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests does what you need.

```
import requests
req = requests.get('http://www.example.com/mirror_me.txt')
if req.status_code == 200:
    mirror = req.content
elif req.status_code == 404:
    print('notify me....')
```

Comment: The question is on how to do this with urllib. This is not an answer.

Comment: Then why is the requests tag included?

Comment: On top of that, your answer is talking about urllib2, not urllib.

Answer (score 0):

The response from `urlopen` is a file-like object that can be `read`.

```
a = urllib.urlopen('http://www.example.com/mirror_me.txt')
code = a.getcode()
if code == 200:
    data = a.read()
    <..>
```

`urlib` is deprecated though, [per docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html?highlight=urllib#high-level-interface), should move to `urllib2`. The above code works the same in `urllib2` as well.